# Enumerate all paths through a rose tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tree, multiway-tree

I'm working with a version of a Tree of the type:

```
Tree = Empty | Leaf Event | Split String [(String, Tree)]
```

My aim is to get a function that returns a list of pairs `[(Event,[Int])]` with `[Int]` being the coordinates (the path taken in the tree to reach it) of each Event, i.e if the tree was:

```
Split str [(str2, Leaf event), (str3, Empty)]
```

Then I would want it to return `[event,[0]]`. I want to ignore any empty ends to the tree.

so my function looks like

```
coords :: Tree -> [(Event,[Int])]
coords Empty = []
coords (Leaf event) = [event, []]
```

Then for Split it needs to recursively apply the function on each subtree. I thought of doing:

```
coords Split str xs = zip (coords trees) [1..] where
    trees = [snd(str,tree) | (str,tree) <-xs]
```

But this would give me nested lists of arbitrary length, among a couple of other problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be:

```
coords (Split _ xs) = [ (event, n:path)
      | (n,(_,tree)) <- zip [1..] xs 
      , (event, path) <- coords tree  ]
```

This starts by enumerating the trees in `xs`, using `zip [1..]` as done in the OP. We get a list of kind-of triples `(n,(string,tree))`, and we do not need the `string`. For any such "triple", we recurse with `coords tree`: this produces a list of the form `[(event1, path1), (event2, path2), ...]` where the paths are relative to `tree`, not to `Split str xs`. We need to add `n` in front of every path, so we finally generate `(event, n:path)`.

Comment: Two details: (1) You need an extra `concat` on the outside, or to change the comprehension to `[addN cs {- etc. -} cs <- coords tree {- etc. -}]` (2) Given the usage example in the OP, the indexing should start from `0`.

Comment: @duplode (1) Right! I chose your second solution, and inlined `addN`. (2) I am unsure about starting from 0 since the OP used `zip (...) [1..]`.

Comment: On (2), indeed -- the question is inconsistent on that point, so there isn't much we can do about it.

Comment: @duplode  yes, It should really be [0..]. That was poorly thought out.